# PHP 'date - months' weird behaviour

Tags: php

I have a weird thing going on and I hope someone can help me.
I have this line of code:

```
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("-3 months"));
```

and this is what is printed out: 2022-01

however, when I do

```
echo date('Y-m', strtotime("-2 months"));
```

It gives: 2022-03

why this weird behaviour?

Thx,
Peter

Comment: I assume it's after midnight where you are, so it's April 29. 2 months before that is February 29, which doesn't exist (except in leap years) so it's March 1.

Comment: That is probably the case because it is based on UTC time in their example (does not have a timezone attached to it and it is currently 2:00am UTC)

Comment: @Barmar: that could be the reaon ... february 29!I live in Indonesia and today is april 29 (11.45 am) and april has 30 days.
So 'months - 2' should give February, right? Yesterday this code was working fine but today this weird behaviour happens.